# Placing a phonecall including extension

Tags: android, iphone, titanium, phone-call

I have been trying to call a number from within my Titanium Appcelerator application using various methods. The problem is, that is should dial an extension as well. I have tried the formats "tel:1234567890,34", "tel:1234567890p34", "1234567890w34". And I have tried it using:

```
// method 1
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
  action : Ti.Android.ACTION_CALL,
  data : phoneNumber
});
Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);

// method 2
Ti.Platform.openURL(phoneNumber);
```

All combinations of formats and methods do not work. The "p" is rewritten to "7". Using a comma, everything after the comma is neglected. How can I make an outbound call including an extension?

Comment: AFAIK it is not uniformly possible to inject anything, including touch tones, into the Android outbound audio stream, though there may be hacks available due to the hardware architecture of some devices.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works on Android but I know on iPhone when I wanted to place a phone call with an extension I would use 4 commas (,,,,)

Let me know if it works I'm curious

Example:
1-555-455-4443,,,,8888

*Note I was using the native SDK's (NOT Titanium Appcelerator)