# Calling User Entered Number with Extension

Tags: android, iphone, phone-call

I am trying to design a webpage that will allow the user to enter an extension (e.g 1234) and then press a 'call now' button that will call a predefined number (on ios or android etc) followed by the extension e.g - 02098761234.

Not sure if I need a script of some sort or whether it can be done in HTML but any advice would be much appreciated.

I've looked around on here and found a few similar questions ([Placing a phonecall including extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413355/placing-a-phonecall-including-extension)) but none that talk about doing this from a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a link tag:

```
 <a href="tel:+02098761234">1234</a>
```

Following this logic, your script / web page could dynamically construct this phone number and go to the URL via javascript.